# Second Order Non-Linear Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have the equation $$x_{tt}+cx_t+x=x^2$$ where $c$ is constant and $x=x(t)$.

If the $x^2$ wasn't on the right hand side of the equation then I could solve this easily by the method of characteristics. However since it is there, how do I deal with it? Is there a common transformation to use in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p=x_t$ and consider $p$ as a function if $x$. Then
$$
x_{tt}=\frac{dp}{dt}=p\,\frac{dp}{dx}.
$$
The equation becomes
$$
p\,\frac{dp}{dx}+c\,p+x=x^2.
$$
This is a <strike>linear</strike> first order equation. Solve for $p$ as a function of $x$ and then for $x$ as a function of $t$. Unfortunately it does not seem to have an easy solution.

This procedure can be carried out whenever the independent variable ($t$ in this case) deos not appear explicitely.

Comment: The presence of the term $p(dp/dx)$ forces me to ask:  in what sense is this equation linear?  I'm pretty sure that, in general, for solutions $p_1$, $p_2$, $a p_1 + b p_2$, $a, b \in \Bbb R$ is ***not*** a solution.  Or do I miss something?

Comment: Indeed, this new form doesn't seem to be solvable by using an integrating factor?

Comment: Indeed it is not linear. Thanks for noting it.